# gitlabci integration/e2e test flow

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

What is the best practice for running integration/e2e tests after build with CI? Seems like the common flow is build, test, deploy, however running integration test/e2e requires a build/staging server to run something like selenium. Does anyone have a hello world example of this or example .gitlab-ci.yml file?

Comment: How are you interpreting *test* in "build, test, deploy? As unit test? Then you need to define a "build, unit test, integration test, deploy build process.  The [docs](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/README.html) gives rspec as the test example.  That could easily be your integration tests.  BTW, how are you launching your selenium tests?  Which language bindings?  My advice is to play around with it some more.

Comment: You need to have test versions of those external systems that you hope to test against available to your just built system running on the CI.

Comment: Thanks. Both unit tests using karma and integration tests using webdriver.io and nodejs on top of selenium. My question is really how are people doing this as part of their automated build. Selenium tests require the deployment step first or to some lower life cycle. That's typically an aync process as it takes some amount of time for the server to spin up with the new code. I don't want the selenium tests to start before the code is deployed and running. Also I don't see any examples of people running tests after deploy which makes me think I'm going about this wrong.

Comment: You are going about it correctly.  I use Jenkins and you can condition step execution on the success of previous steps.  So we 1. git pull, 2.Build, 3. run unit tests, 4. run acceptance tests 4. run code coverage 5. deploy to integration environment. So asynchronous or not, don't start the next step until it has finished. gitlabci has to have a way to do this.  To speed things up acceptance tests can be split and run concurrently (make sure that there are no shared dependencies) but they all have to finish before the next step starts.

Comment: Tests take place on the CI. The last step is deploy to integration for everybody to use.  You either have to have CI versions of the e2e external apps or lock integration out until the build finishes (yuck).